# passing data when returning to main activity(Intent) what I've done wrong?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to android . This might be the simplest question of all !! but I couldn't figure out whats gone wrong here,

I was trying to create a basic example for passing values through intent.So I need to pass data to Main Activity when I close my  Second Activity  here is the code

IntentTest1(MainActivity)

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
MyClass.myToast("Clicked",getApplicationContext());
Intent myIntent = newIntent(getApplicationContext(),SecondPage.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent,0); 
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        if(data.hasExtra("title"))
        {
    MyClass.myToast(""+resultCode+""+requestCode, getApplicationContext());
    String str = data.getExtras().getString("title").toString();
    titleText.setText(str); 
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

SeconPage

```
public void finish()
{

Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Intenttest1.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("Welcome Back!!","title");
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    //      below was for tosting and it works!!
MyClass.myToast("finally",getApplicationContext());
super.finish();
}
```

I think there is some mistake in receiving the intent ,I couldn't figure out.
Answers and Advises are needed
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is when you create your `Intent` to send back to the first `Activity`. Since you are using `startActivityForResult()` you want to use an empty constructor. So change

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Intenttest1.class);
```

to

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

The second problem is that you have your `key/value` pair backwards in your `Extras`. The `key`, which is what you look for with `getStringExtra()` etc... should be the first in the pair. So this

```
returnIntent.putExtra("Welcome Back!!","title");
```

should be

```
returnIntent.putExtra("title", "Welcome Back!!");
```

**Off-topic**

I would consider using relevant names as your `params`. For example, I would change your `onClick()` from

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
```

to

```
public void onClick(View view)
```

`view`, `v`, or something similar makes more sense since the argument actually is a view and it will be more readable

I would also recommend using the `Activity` `Context` for your `Intent` which you can get from the argument (the `View`) passed into `onClick()`. So change it to

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
     MyClass.myToast("Clicked",getApplicationContext());
     Intent myIntent = newIntent(v.getContext(),SecondPage.class);
     startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
```

Comment: You're welcome! And to answer your question on the other answer about `Context` and where to use `this`, [see this very good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955)

Comment: If you use `this` inside a `listener`, such as `onClick()`, it will typically be wrong because it will refer to the inner class and not the `Activity`.

Comment: One little Doubt is why we are passing 0 with startActivityForResult? I didn't use that value anywhere else in my example code.

Comment: Look at the documentation but that gets passed back to `onActivityForResult()` as the `RequestCode`. You could have different static variables in case you have multiple `startActivityForResult()`s in the same `Activity` such as calling the camera, picking contacts, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
if(data.hasExtra("Welcome Back!!"))
```

instead of

```
if(data.hasExtra("title"))
```

in `onActivityResult`. `Welcome Back!!` is the key and `title` is the value for that key in your extras.

Comment: Got it Thanks a lot , I should have been more careful when I am writing code :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Intenttest1.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("Key name here in ur case title","Value name");
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
//      below was for tosting and it works!!
 MyClass.myToast("finally",getApplicationContext());
super.finish();
```

}

Comment: nope!!:( its not working!! Thanks Anyway and Now I've one more doubt? If it'll work? whats the difference? where I can use 'this' and where I can't ..